# Process substitution, /dev/fd/63

Tags: file-descriptor, fileoutputstream, process-substitution

I have a script that takes a file name as input in $1, and processes it...and creates an output file as ${1}.output.log and it works fine. e.g. if i tried 
./myscript filename.txt

It'll process and generate output file with name: filename.txt.output.log

But When I tried to substitute a process to give input to this script like 
./myscript <(echo something), it failed as it cannot create a file anymore with ${1}. output.log ; because now $1 is not an actual file and doesn't exist in my working directory where script is suppose to create an output.

Any suggestions to work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that when using process substitution you  are trying to create a file in /dev, more specifically, /dev/fd/63.output.log
I recommend doing this:

```
output_file="$( sed 's|/dev/fd/|./process_substitution-|' <<< ${1} ).output.log"
echo "my output" >> "$output_file"
```

We use sed to replace /dev/fd/ to ./process_substitution- so the file gets created in the current working directory (pwd) with the name process_substitution-63.output.log